# CSS Variable height does not work correctly

Tags: css

I am getting a weird behavior when I make height as a variable `$main-height` in CSS.

```
height: $main-height/2;
```

Result of checkbox check

[image]

Demo fiddles are listed below:

[Hard coded height JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/ngkvysx8/7/)

[Variable height JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/ngkvysx8/8/)

When I use the same code in CodePen it works - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJopgY) .

How to fix this in jsFiddle and my HTML?

Please note that I have no experience in LESS/SASS.

Comment: click the little gear in the top/right of the css box and choose "scss" as the language

Comment: As Michael wrote, then it works just fine...https://jsfiddle.net/ngkvysx8/9/

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks. How do I do the same in my HTML page? I need to include it as SCSS?

Comment: With your HTML page you need to run your SCSS compiler up on page load

Comment: @Lijo where did you get this code? You can click the top/right arrow thing in the css panel in codepen and "view compiled css" and just copy/paste that. That will compile the scss into normal css.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, but then OP loses the concept of using variables

Comment: Can't the OP just use `calc()` instead and not use variables? It's not that easy to install LESS/SCSS for someone who has 0 experience with it.

Comment: @LGSon right but they're saying they have no experience with LESS/SCSS. I'm assuming they found this code and just want to use the CSS, not re-use variables with CSS out of this context.

Comment: @Huangism If one need variables, one need variables

Comment: @MichaelCoker Agree...

Comment: @Lijo As you have little knowledge use the hard coded. If you still want to learn, check this: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: @Lijo May I also suggest you close this as _a problem that can no longer be reproduced_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. Based on the comments, I am adding it as answer.

Why the HTML is not working: This code need to be compiled as `CSS`.

How to make it work in JsFiddle:  On top/right of the css box and choose "scss" as the language. (as mentioned by @MichaelCoker)

How to get Compiled CSS: In codepen, on top/right arrow in the css panel, select  "View compiled css" to get the compiled CSS (as mentioned by @MichaelCoker)